# Mapping represented sequences with representative sequences

Tags: traminer

How is it possible to find out which "represented sequence(s)" are represented by which “representative sequence(s)”?

For example, in the following example, is there a way to find the original 627 sequences represented by “r1”?

```
data(biofam)
biofam.lab <- c("Parent", "Left", "Married", "Left+Marr",
"Child", "Left+Child", "Left+Marr+Child", "Divorced")
biofam.seq <- seqdef(biofam, 10:25, labels=biofam.lab)
## Computing the distance matrix
costs <- seqsubm(biofam.seq, method="TRATE")
biofam.om <- seqdist(biofam.seq, method="OM", sm=costs)
## Representative set using the neighborhood density criterion
biofam.rep <- seqrep(biofam.seq, diss=biofam.om, criterion="density")
biofam.rep
summary(biofam.rep)

[>] criterion: density 
[>] 2000 sequence(s) in the original data set
[>] 4 representative sequences
[>] overall quality: 0.08113734 
[>] statistics for the representative set:


        na na(%)  nb nb(%)    SD   MD    DC    V      Q
r1     627  31.4 225 11.25  4566 7.28  4856 4.73   5.97
r2     577  28.8 123  6.15  4305 7.46  5175 5.05  16.81
r3     411  20.5 115  5.75  2658 6.47  2394 4.34 -11.04
r4     385  19.2  93  4.65  3006 7.81  3393 5.57  11.42
Total 2000 100.0 556 27.80 14535 7.27 15818 7.91   8.11

    na: number of assigned objects
    nb: number of objects in the neighborhood
    SD: sum of the na distances to the representative
    MD: mean of the na distances to the representative
    DC: sum of the na distances to the center of the complete set
    V: discrepancy of the subset
    Q: quality of the representative
```

A complementary question. It would be great if there would be more explanation/clarification on how "na" and "nb" should be read and interpreted. For example, are the 4 representative sequences (r1, r2, r3, r4) representing the 2000 sequences or just the 556 sequences?

I tried to find answers to my questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sequences assigned to each representative can be retrieved from the `"Distances` attribute of the object returned by `seqdef`. I illustrate following up your example:

```
## "Distances" attribute of object returned by seqrep
rep.dist <- attr(biofam.rep,"Distances")
rep.dist[1:9,] # first 9 rows to show how it looks out

#          1692       221     1167 1245
# 1167       NA        NA 0.000000   NA
# 514        NA 10.000000       NA   NA
# 1013       NA  9.794079       NA   NA
# 275        NA  1.945416       NA   NA
# 2580       NA  5.954724       NA   NA
# 773   1.96818        NA       NA   NA
# 1187 13.89761        NA       NA   NA
# 47         NA  9.704456       NA   NA
# 2091       NA        NA 3.957049   NA

## retrieving assigned representative
rep.grp <- apply(rep.dist, 1, which.min)

seqdplot(biofam.seq, group=rep.grp, border=NA)
```

[image]

```
## sequences assigned to 1st representative
seq.rep1 <- biofam.seq[rep.grp==1,]
nrow(seq.rep1)

# 627
```

Regarding your complementary question:

Each sequence is assigned to the closer representative sequence and `na[i]` is the total number of sequences assigned to `ri`.

Now, the neighborhood of each representative is defined by the `pradius` argument (by default, 10% of the maximum distance). `nb[i]` is the number out of the `na[i]` sequences that are in the neighborhood of `ri`.

A sequence can be assigned to a representative without being in its neighborhood. It can also be in the neighborhood of a representative but be assigned (i.e., closer) to another representative.

For the example, the sum of the `nb`'s tells us that 556 sequences are covered, i.e., in the neighborhood of at least one of the representatives. The sum of the `na`'s is always the total number of sequences.